# RFID tag ID into a text field

Tags: java

I am working on a project to import an RFID tag ID into a text field from a COM1 port connected to client PC .A high level view of the program is:

Page loads -> runs myApplet -> returns a string of the RFID tag ID to a text field on the page ->click save button->text field saved in DB-> ends applet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a javascript function from your Java applet. This [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html) will help you.